# Passing an array of objects to SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, arrays, sql-server

I have 2 tables

- `payment` (**payment_id**, otherCosts, GarageCosts)
- `spareparts` (payment_id, sparepartId, sparePartQty)

In `payment` table `payment_id` is autogenerated. Apart from `otherCosts` and `garagecosts` values, in my C# asp.net application there is an array of objects with

```
{ sparepartId : 'Somevalue', sparePartQty : 'somevalue' }
```

What I need to do is in a stored procedure first enter the record into payment table with garage costs and others costs value. Then return the last generated payment ID and enter it to `spareParts` table as `paymentId` for each of the value pairs in the array.

What is the way to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Look at Table-Valued Parameters - [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510489.aspx), [ADO.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx). These are types *designed* to hold multiple values (SQL Server has no concept of arrays)

Comment: do you need to insert multiple records to `payment` table and their respective records to `spareparts`, or just one `payment` and it's respective `spareparts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your tags I am going to assume we are talking about SQL Server / T-SQL.
You could do all this in one stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Foo ... /* input parameters */
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PaymentId int

    INSERT INTO payment(otherCosts, GarageCosts) VALUES (...)
    SET @PaymentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    INSERT INTO spareparts(payment_id, sparepartId, sparePartQty) VALUES(@PaymentId, ...) 

END
GO
```

You may want to also look into @@IDENTITY but make sure you read about [@@IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) and [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) and understand the risks associated with the first one.

If you need to have two separate sprocs you can do that too and here is how the first sproc would look like. Note that the `@PaymentId` is an output parameter which means that the caller can retrieve it and pass it to the second procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Foo 
    /* input parameters */
    @PaymentId int OUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO payment(otherCosts, GarageCosts) VALUES (...)
    SET @PaymentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

**Edit** - after the scope of the question was clarified:

If you need to call the second stored procedure and pass it an array of parameters, with SQL Server 2008 or newer you can use TVP (Table Value Parameters). To see how you can use them in stored procedures and how you can pass them from C# code see [Table Value Parameters in SQL Server 2008 and .NET (C#)](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/) or [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can also use TVPs with the solution where you only have one sproc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your code would do the trick if of my paymentId has only one record associated in the second table. But what I need to to is for one paymentId in first table, I need to enter multiple records to second table. Seems like I need 2 SPs

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem try this

First insert your data in `payment` table with `otherCosts` and `GarageCosts`.

Then create a procedure to get the latest stored `payment_id` from `payment` table

```
create procedure select_last_payment_id
as
begin
    select top 1 payment_id
    from payment
    order by payment_id desc  
end
```

Lastly get that `payment_id` by running stored procedure and assigning it to  `payment_id` of `spareparts` table and storing `spareparts` data.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: That may not work in an environment that is multithreaded or if this code runs on a server (like a web front end server) where multiple clients can be served concurrently. By the time the procedure `select_last_payment_id` is run, another thread may have added another row. There is also a simpler establish pattern to do this based on @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: @TFrost  Same as i mentioned to Ladi. My problem is not getting the lastiD. I need to enter multiple records to the second table with the lastId of first table

Comment: @IsankaLakshan : sorry, I misunderstood the question.